# Python restructuring dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have the following dict in Python

```
{1500: 2, 1400: 1, 700: 10}
```

and I have a hard time turning it into the following:

```
[{"x": 1500, "y": 2}, {"x": 1400, "y": 1}, {"x": 700, "y": 10}]
```

How do I do this? Is there some list comprehension for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is.

```
[{"x": k, "y": v} for k, v in my_dict.items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myDict = {1500: 2, 1400: 1, 700: 10}

[{'x': key, 'y': myDict[key]} for key in myDict]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use a simple for loop:

```
data = {1500: 2, 1400: 1, 700: 10}
result = []

for x, y in data.items():
    result.append({"x": x, "y": y})
```